# Is tipping allowed on the Ethereum StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion

I recall that users on bitcointalk and other crypto discussion boards post wallet addresses that people can send tips to.  I haven't looked at many profiles here so maybe users are already posting them here as well.  Are there any rules or requirements for posting ether, bitcoin, or other addresses to receive tips?  If not, should there be?  It would be annoying if users posted addresses in every answer they gave - on the other hand it's not a problem yet so no need to add bureaucracy at this point.

Answer (score 13):

What @eth said. In general the reward model of stack exchange is pretty straight forward: Good and helpful content get's [upvoted](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). Upvotes generate [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and reputation enables users [privileges](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

And privileges are important because this site is *run by you*, the community. High reputation enables you [access to moderator tools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), [protecting questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), [deleting posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and finally even [access to site analytics](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics).

However, you should be allowed to post a tipping address in your profile. As long as you don't post it along with content or advertise for tipping, you should be fine with that.

Comment: Yeah, I think the fact that SE has a well-developed reward model in place already is an important point for newcomers.

Comment: To clarify: you can post almost anything you want in your profile, short of straight-out illegal stuff. Even advertising for tips is okay - in your profile. If it leaks into questions, answers, comments etc, it's spam.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion we shouldn't allow posting of addresses in answers; it seems that people could post a tipping address on their profile if they desire and could get tips that way.

Comment: I think we now need a standard comment when removing tipping from an answer. I'll let you handle this and follow your lead in the future: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3898/300

Answer (score 8):

I think a free tipping / donating is important in the crypto space as so much is open source and so many people create amazing things... And get not much in return. However, I agree that including a tip address as part of an answer / asking for tips for your answer is taking it a step too far.

However, I do try to include the donation addresses of the developer (if they have it posted in the github or whatever) when my answer includes a library or service or site that solves the OPs problem (not my own, though).

Comment: someone could build a [stackapp](http://stackapps.com/) to enable tipping on our site.

Answer (score 3):

a tip contract would be a good use case : 
send eth to the contract, precising tip address, tip amount, stackexchange question id

Comment: that's a good idea, maybe a good was for people to try out a simple contract.  so you're thinking the asking user would create the contract?  though i agree with others here that keeping the tipping address out of answers seems important so maybe also keeping contract info out of questions is also important.  avoiding the SE site from becoming a free market with currency.

Comment: The bad news is that it will also generate a lot of questions about how to use this tipping contract and people won't ask in this meta site.

Answer (score 3):

At Oraclize we have designed this [PoC DApp](http://dapps.oraclize.it/stackexchange-bounty/) for depositing bounties over StackExchange questions. Right now it only works in testnet, but it can be developed in a reasonable time to a fully fledge DApp on Ethereum main-net, if the community like the concept. 
You can read our blogpost [here](http://blog.oraclize.it/2016/05/17/stackexchange-bounty-dapp/) and take part in the reddit discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4jq88s/oraclizebased_stackexchange_bounty_%C3%B0app_an/). Feedbacks are REALLY welcome! :)

Comment: Cool, how does it link users and addresses?

Comment: You have to add your address in the location field on your user profile, like mine. We can even open a new thread if you guys want to give a hand helping us moving forward :)