# Is there a sidechain token that would be suitable for use as a reward system for greater engagement with the Ethereum Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A layer for microtransactions for tracking and rewarding a broader set of activity than the standard StackExchange badges/reputation could help accelerate participation. Which existing sidechains/solutions might be a good fit?

Comment: If this isn't a question for meta I will ask it in the regular Ethereum stack exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the request, but are these related? [Is tipping allowed on the Ethereum StackExchange site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions), [Should crypto-bounties be allowed in questions?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/510)

Comment: The fundamental question is what current ethereum solutions are viable for microtransactions (with the presumption that it would be a sidechain?). The context is an example of adding a token based reward on top of the existing stackexchange reputation/privilege/badge mechanism. Not tipping, not bounty for specific questions, but augmenting existing system with actual token rewards.

Comment: For reference: https://delegatecall.com/

Comment: (Was going to suggest you look at how they do it, but...: https://delegatecall.com/questions/is-delegatecall-is-open-source-if-so-where-is-the-github-repo-ed31e763-f5b8-4283-9081-d690f3536a27)